# Non-Linear data fitting for kinetic data

Tags: python, modeling, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, chemometrics

I am trying to fit a two_site model which I derived, (basically, rate as a function of pressures of reactants and products) to my experimental data. Just want to check if the logic below is fine, because the fit parameters are not ideal as I expected. Of course, this means that the model could be wrong, however, that possibility is less.

Also, I have theta_star and theta_prime values, which have to between 0 and 1. Since they are implicit equations, I have tried to compute them numerically. I think it makes sense, but would be great to have a second opinion on the fitting process.

```
# partial_pressures and Temp are loaded from excel file
def two_site(partial_pressures, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0, T):
    pA, pB, pC = partial_pressures

    k3 = k0 * np.exp(-37000 / (8.314 * T))
    S = (k3 / k4) * K1 * K2 * pA * pB

    # theta_prime and theta_star
    num = 50
    theta_prime = 0.05
    theta_star = 0.05
    
    for _ in range(num):
        theta_star_new = 1 / (1 + K2 * pB + np.sqrt(S * theta_prime / theta_star))
        theta_prime_new = 1 / (1 + K1 * pA + pC / K5 + np.sqrt(S * theta_star / theta_prime))
        theta_star = np.maximum(0, np.minimum(1, theta_star_new))  
        theta_prime = np.maximum(0, np.minimum(1, theta_prime_new))
        
#     print("theta_star:", theta_star)
#     print("theta_prime:", theta_prime)  


    rate = k3 * K1 * K2 * pB * pA * theta_star * theta_prime
    return rate




# Step 3: Objective Function
def objective(params):
    K1, K2, k4, K5, k0 = params
    model_rates = two_site(partial_pressures.T, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0, Temp)
    return np.abs((model_rates - experimental_rates)/experimental_rates) * 100


# Step 4: least_squares optimization

initial_params = [4.6, 100000, 50, 10, 100]  # K1, K2, k3(not included - should be small), k4(fast step), K5, k0
lb = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]                 # K1, K2, k4, K5, k0
ub = [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf]
bounds1 = (lb,ub)

result = least_squares(objective, initial_params, bounds=bounds1)
K1n_fit, K2n_fit, k4n_fit, K5n_fit, k0n_fit = result.x

model_rates2 = two_site(partial_pressures.T, K1n_fit, K2n_fit, k4n_fit, K5n_fit, k0n_fit, Temp)
percentage_error2 = np.abs((model_rates2 - experimental_rates) / experimental_rates) * 100


print("\n Model rates 2",model_rates2)
print("\n")
print(K1n_fit)
print(K2n_fit)
print(k4n_fit)
print(K5n_fit)
print("k0: ", k0n_fit)
print("\n")

print("\nPercentage error least squares are :",percentage_error2)
```